# OpenCV cvCapture compressed data

Tags: c++, opencv, rtsp

Can I get compressed data from cvCapture, which is stored into buffer after cvGrabFrame, before using cvRetrieveFrame? I need to keep  them in the an archive of compressed frames.

I use cvCaptureFromFile for getting rtsp stream from Axis IP camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see it it's not possible. CvCapture is a black box structure. There is not really a possibility to access the data inside.

There is the function [cv::imencode](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imencode) to compress images. It is not optimal to compress the image again but it should work.

By the way, you're using the old C API and there is a newer API for C++ that makes capturing more elegant: [cv::VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture).